# How to apply sharp corner radius with border on UIView in swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, border, layer, cornerradius

I want to set corner radius on bottom left and right side with border on UIView. here is code. **issue is it's not display SHARP in 1.5 border **

```
class BorderView: UIView {

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let color = UIColor.red
    let color2 = UIColor.brown

    //// Rectangle Drawing
    let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200), byRoundingCorners: [.bottomRight, .bottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
    rectanglePath.close()
    color2.setFill()
    rectanglePath.fill()
    color.set()
    rectanglePath.lineWidth = 1.5
    rectanglePath.stroke()

 }
}
```

**OutPut**

[image]

**expected output**

[image]

Comment: By "sharp" do you mean "smooth" or "pointy"?

Comment: Have you tried using a line width that isn't a fraction? so either `1` or `2`

Comment: hey @rmaddy I want "smooth"

Answer (score 6):

If you use the border and corner properties on `CALayer`, it should do it all for you.

```
// Probably inside init
layer.borderWidth = 1.5
layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

layer.cornerRadius = 10
layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
```

Comment: Thanks @clever its display "Sharp" and "Smooth" :)

Comment: Could you please a favor ? I want to set border only 3 side Left , Right and Bottom with sharp corner radius.

Comment: There is no option to add a border only to certain sides. I position the view inside its superview so that that top is above the top of the superview so that the border will be clipped by the superviews bounds.